# Question about probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Here is the question:
Suppose that the probability density function of random vector $(X,Y)$ is $f(x,y)=\frac{a}{y}$ for $0<x\leqslant y<1$ and $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise. Here $a$ represents an unknown constant.
Please find out the value of $a$.

Here is my answer:
$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{a}{y} dy=1$

$a\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{y} dy=1$

$a[ln(y)]_{0}^{1} = 1$

$a[ln(1)-ln(0)] = 1$

$a[0-1] = 1$

$a=-1$

But later, I realized that the answer might be wrong because $0<y<1$ and $f(x,y)=\frac{-1}{y}$, which is less than 0. Can $f(x,y)$ be less than 0 in this case or any other case? If I am wrong, what is going to be the correct solution?

Addition to the question above, I have already known the mistake I had. The above question I got the answer is $a=1$.

Comment: Absolutely positively *no*:  a pdf can never be negative.  One of your problems is that you integrated over just a single variable of a two-variable pdf.

Comment: What happened to $x$?

Comment: Why are you only integrating over the bounds of $y$? You were given a joint pdf, so it's a double integral that must satisfy the normalization.

Comment: Also, since when is $\ln(0)$ defined, let alone equal to 1????

Comment: Here's a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to give you some really awesome tricks to make your posts pristine

Answer (score 1):

So your region $S$ is defined as a triangle between $y$-axis, line $x=y$ and line $y=1$. As you wrote you need to integrate it to one,
$$
1 = \iint_S (a/y) dxdy = \int_{y=0}^{y=1} \int_{x=0}^{x=y} \frac{adxdy}{y}
  = a \int_0^1 \frac{dy}{y} \int_{x=0}^{x=y} dx
$$
can you take it from here?

Comment: Sorry to bother again, may you check the second question above? Thank you soooooooooooooo much!

Answer (score 1):

It should be
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^y \frac{a}{y}dxdy=1$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{a}{y} \int_0^y dx dy=1$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{a}{y} y dy =1$$
$$a\int_0^1 dy = 1$$
$$a = 1$$

Comment: Sorry to bother again, may you check the second question above? Thank you soooooooooooooo much!

Comment: Most people use `\,` on either side quantities represented by two separate symbols—such as differentials—to separate them.